# Ghostscript looks for dyld library in the wrong place

Tags: x11, ghostscript

I'm on Macos 10.14.5. I run Ghostscript via Macports, and recently upgraded to Ghostscript 9.27. Ever since I upgraded, most of what I use Ghostscript for (Imagemagick file conversions) doesn't work anymore. I made the silly mistake of deleting the old version of Ghostscript in Macports (yeah ...).

Essentially, Ghostscript crashes with an 'Abort trap: 6' error. Example? I try to convert a PDF to PNG. I get this:

```
[ghostscript library 9.27] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r600x600' '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/k0/m6mz3d055m75782ynnkt2k0w0000gn/T/magick-5910MkmWy1yIM0tx%d' '-f/var/folders/k0/m6mz3d055m75782ynnkt2k0w0000gn/T/magick-5910gs9cNcP8C7cU' '-f/var/folders/k0/m6mz3d055m75782ynnkt2k0w0000gn/T/magick-5910iJZ-CiPdfIWp'Abort trap: 6
```

I believe this has to to with '/usr/local/bin/gs-X11' being unable to find the correct directory for a dyld library. When I run gs-X11, I get this:

/usr/local/bin/gs-X11 
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs-X11
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

The 'libXt.6.dylib' library exists on my file system, but not in '/opt/X11/', but in '/opt/local/lib/'.

How do I get Ghostscript to use the correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript doesn't build an executable called 'gs-X11', the executable should be called simply 'gs'.

It 'sounds like' you've picked up a pre-built binary from somewhere, which has been built to expect X-Windows support, and that support is supplied by a system shared library, and as you rightly say, not where you have it installed.

I don't think you can (easily) modify the binary to look elsewhere for the system library, but I'm not a Mac developer so I might be mistaken.

Given that you have the library already present you could try simply copying it to /opt/X11/lib.

Or you could try the source you got the binary from and look for a non-X-Windows version. (or ask them, presumably the Macports people hwo to fix the problem)

Or you could build Ghostscript yourself from source.

To build from source you'll need gcc and the autotools, you can pick up autoconf, automake and libtool from HomeBrew if you don't already have them. With that, get the source tarball from the www.ghostscript.com downloads page, untar it somewhere convenient and then, from that folder do "./autogen.sh" and then "make". That should build a version of Ghostscript compatible with your system.

To be honest, this isn't a Ghostscript question really, more of a Mac system question.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem on a machine that had various versions of X11 installed (and uninstalled) through both [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) and [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/). I seem to have solved the problem by providing a symlink between the missing /opt/X11 and the existing /opt/local where the needed things exist:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local /opt/X11
sudo ln -s /opt/local /opt/X11R6
```

Similar problems seem to sometimes occur when /usr/local/X11 and /usr/local/X11R6 are non-existing, but in my case the /usr/local/X11 already had a symlink to /opt/X11 (as does /usr/local/X11R6 )

Probably to really fix everything properly, I should [completely uninstall MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html), and [completely uninstall XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/FAQs.html), and remove all the symlinks, then restart the computer to make sure it is all clear. Then reinstall it all and hope that the installers get everything in the right places. Perhaps [redoing my MacTeX LaTeX installation](https://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html) would also be wise.